# Ansible trouble parsing JSON to get correct UUIDs to poweron VMs

Tags: json, parsing, ansible

making an API GET cal I get the following JSON structure:

```
{
  "metadata": {
    "grand_total_entities": 231,
    "total_entities": 0,
    "count": 231
  },
  "entities": [
   {
      "allow_live_migrate": true,
      "gpus_assigned": false,
      "ha_priority": 0,
      "memory_mb": 1024,
      "name": "test-ansible2",
      "num_cores_per_vcpu": 2,
      "num_vcpus": 1,
      "power_state": "off",
      "timezone": "UTC",
      "uuid": "e1aff9d4-c834-4515-8c08-235d1674a47b",
      "vm_features": {
        "AGENT_VM": false
      },
      "vm_logical_timestamp": 1
    },
   {
      "allow_live_migrate": true,
      "gpus_assigned": false,
      "ha_priority": 0,
      "memory_mb": 1024,
      "name": "test-ansible1",
      "num_cores_per_vcpu": 1,
      "num_vcpus": 1,
      "power_state": "off",
      "timezone": "UTC",
      "uuid": "4b3b315e-f313-43bb-941b-03c298937b4d",
      "vm_features": {
        "AGENT_VM": false
      },
      "vm_logical_timestamp": 1
    },
   {
      "allow_live_migrate": true,
      "gpus_assigned": false,
      "ha_priority": 0,
      "memory_mb": 4096,
      "name": "test",
      "num_cores_per_vcpu": 1,
      "num_vcpus": 2,
      "power_state": "off",
      "timezone": "UTC",
      "uuid": "fbe9a1ac-cf45-4efa-9d65-b3257548a9f4",
      "vm_features": {
        "AGENT_VM": false
      },
      "vm_logical_timestamp": 17
    },
   ]
}
```

In my Ansible playbook I register a variable holding this content.
I need to get a list of UUID of "test-ansible1" and "test-ansible2" but I'm having a hard time finding the best way to to this.
Note that I have another variable holding the list of names for which I need to lookup the UUID.

The need is to use those UUIDs to fire a poweron command for all UUIDs corresponding to specific names.

How would you guys do that?

I've taken a number of approaches but I can't seem to get what I want so I prefer an uninfluenced opinion.

P.S.: This is what Nutanix AHV returns as a get of all vms thgough APIs. There seems to me no way to get only specific VMs JSON information but only all VMs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some Jinja2 magic for you:

```
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ mynames | map('extract', dict(test_json | json_query('entities[].[name,uuid]'))) | list }}"
    vars:
      mynames:
        - test-ansible1
        - test-ansible2
```

Explanation:

1. `test_json | json_query('entities[].[name,uuid]')` reduces your original json data to a list of elements which are lists of two items – name value and uuid value:

   ```
   [
     [
       "test-ansible2",
       "e1aff9d4-c834-4515-8c08-235d1674a47b"
     ],
     [
       "test-ansible1",
       "4b3b315e-f313-43bb-941b-03c298937b4d"
     ],
     [
       "test",
       "fbe9a1ac-cf45-4efa-9d65-b3257548a9f4"
     ]
   ]
   ```

   BTW you can use http://jmespath.org/ to test query statements.
2. `dict(...)` when applied to such structure (list of "touples") generates a dictionary:

   ```
   {
       "test": "fbe9a1ac-cf45-4efa-9d65-b3257548a9f4",
       "test-ansible1": "4b3b315e-f313-43bb-941b-03c298937b4d",
       "test-ansible2": "e1aff9d4-c834-4515-8c08-235d1674a47b"
   }
   ```
3. Then we apply `extract` filter as [per documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#extracting-values-from-containers) to fetch only required elements:

   ```
   [
       "4b3b315e-f313-43bb-941b-03c298937b4d",
       "e1aff9d4-c834-4515-8c08-235d1674a47b"
   ]
   ```

Comment: Thank you Konstantin, this was very informational and I can see how difficult it would have been for me to get there.
Following your help I can easily to the point where I get the "list of touples" but when I apply the extract filter it errors out "An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: KeyError: u'names'
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.", "stdout": ""}"

The variable I use is called "names" as opposed to your "mynames" but the content is just like yours.